# React native android build from Source problem

Tags: react-native

**Plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.codegen'] was not found in any of the following sources:**

[Capture screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsRps.png)

I am build react native from source (follow by this step : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/wiki/Building-from-source).
I found this Error. How can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Finally I give up using master. I just use the last release version 0.63 which does not use codegen, and it works. One more thing that I encountered but not shown on document is the hermes/DebuggerAPI.h import issue. The solution is to copy all files under node_modules/hermes-engine/android/include/hermes to node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/hermes.

Answer (score 0):

I think right now, it is better to build directly in React Native repo, rather than build in your app's repo as a dependency. Build react native, and then push the whole repo with artifacts to GitHub. Use GitHub repo's URL to install your custom react native.

Here is what I have done to build patched RN (mostly just following the [wiki](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/wiki/Building-from-source#publish-your-own-version-of-react-native)):

```sh
git clone https://github.com/facebook/react-native
cd react-native
git checkout v0.64.1 # or any other release

# now make changes to the code

# build android artifacts
docker run --rm --name rn-build -v $PWD:/pwd -w /pwd reactnativecommunity/react-native-android /bin/sh -c "./gradlew installArchives --no-daemon"
```

---

Note: if the gradle daemon unexpectedly disappears, try minimize the max ram usage in the root  `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

and check `./gradlew` is invoked with `--no-daemon`; this may help a bit.

---

After the build succeeds, include build artifacts `android` in the git:

```sh
git add android --force
git commit -m 'Release for some patches'
git checkout -b release-fix-something
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myusername/react-native
git push origin release-fix-something:master
```

In your app's repo, install react-native by your fork:

```sh
yarn add https://github.com/myusername/react-native.git
```